# .htaccess file mod_rewrite clean url not working

Tags: .htaccess

So I want the usual thing from the .htaccess file. www.example.com/article.php?title=my_title should be replaced with www.example.com/article/my_title, however I cannot seem to get it to work. As of right now I can get the .php to drop and I suspect that might be some of the problem. (also I get http://example.com to go to http://www.example.com) Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
rewriteengine on

## this is the piece that is not working
RewriteRule ^title/(.*) article.php?arr=title/$1

rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
rewriterule ^example\/(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301]

RewriteBase /

## Hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

## Error document (needs to have a 404 page created)
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these specific routing rules **before** any rules that generally apply to php files. So just under your `rewriteengine on`, add:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/article\.php\?title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?article/(.*)$ /article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Then the rest of your rules.

Comment: I think I am getting a redirect loop by adding the suggested code, is there something I need to change?

Comment: @kricket what URL are you going to that causes a loop or 500 error? I put all of these in a blank htaccess file and I don't have any issues using URI's that test each rule.

Comment: www.example.com/article.php?title=something then it correctly takes me to www.example.com/article/something however that is giving me a 500 internal service error.

Comment: @kricket As I posted in another comment, [that works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tHZIp.png). You sure your php file isn't doing something bad? 500 server errors aren't only caused by stuff in htaccess gone wrong.

Comment: I thought the php might have caused it as well so I deleted all the php from the page and I am still getting the error. I will update the .htaccess to its current state.

Comment: @kricket What does your error logs say, it'll tell you whether it's php, or something misconfigured

Comment: on godaddy so had to enable error logs, however I went into .htaccess and changed the .php part to html and created a test html file still getting the same 500 internal error